# What is the difference in meaning between 'visage' and 'countenance'?

Tags: meaning, nouns

Is there any usage or definition difference between **visage** and **countenance**? From the dictionary definitions, they appear to be the same.

Comment: What did you find in the dictionary?

Comment: They are both rare enough (at least in standard US English) that they do not carry any peculiar connotations for most people using/hearing them, so I would count them as synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

The entires in the Merrian-Webster are the following:

- Visage: the face, countenance, or appearance of a person or sometimes an animal
- Countenance:  face, visage; especially :  the face as an indication of mood, emotion, or character

And the entries in the Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary

- Visage: a person's face
- Countenance: the appearance of a person's face : a person's expression

So they are quit similar, but someones visage is someone's actual face, and someone's countenance is someone's (facial) expression.

Comment: My gut instinct is that "visage" is independent of an observer while "countenance" implies an observer or at least a reflection.

Comment: "She said with a smiling countenance,"They call me Jack Munro."

Comment: Is there any difference between these words, visage and countenance, and the word expression?

Comment: The word *expression* can mean the same as *countenance*  in some contexts, but *expression*  can also be applied to, for example, how someone's voice  sounds. The following is part of the M-W entry of expression: The way one's face looks or one's voice sounds that shows one's feelings. (Expression has besides this some other meanings.)